# How can I use D3 tree data in the VEGA Api?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vega

I am trying to render D3 tree data using the Vega API.

The [Vega Tree documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/tree/) states that Vega uses the d3 tree hierarchy. That suggests it should be possible. The Vega page even includes a link to the D3 hierarchy, which looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Eve",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Cain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Seth",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enos"
        },
        {
          "name": "Noam"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Abel"
    },
    {
      "name": "Awan",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enoch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Azura"
    }
  ]
}
```

But using this directly in a Vega Tree diagram does not work.

[Vega's own tree example includes a data file that does work](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/tree-layout/), but the data format looks completely different. Is there a way to transform the D3 data hierarchy to the format that Vega supports? The Vega docs talk about transforms but I can't find an example.

The required Vega format looks like this. It uses ID's to know who the parent node is, instead of nested arrays.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "flare"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "analytics",
    "parent": 1
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "cluster",
    "parent": 2
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
    "parent": 3,
    "size": 3938
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "CommunityStructure",
    "parent": 3,
    "size": 3812
}
```

How can I use D3 formatted tree data in Vega?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it with Vega, but you can convert a hierarchy with a little helper function as follows:

```js
data = {
"name": "Eve",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Cain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Seth",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enos"
        },
        {
          "name": "Noam"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Abel"
    },
    {
      "name": "Awan",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enoch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Azura"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(flatten(data));

function flatten(hierarchy) {
  let ar = [];
  let i = 0;
  
  let hierarchyWithID = d3.hierarchy(hierarchy).each(d => d.id = i++);
  
  ar = hierarchyWithID.descendants().map(d => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.name = d.data.name;
    obj.id = d.id;
    if (d.parent) { obj.parent = d.parent.id;}
    if (d.size) { obj.size = d.size;}
    return obj;
  });
  
  return ar;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

or alternatively, a version without functions from d3.js (assigning different id's):

```js
data = {
"name": "Eve",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Cain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Seth",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enos"
        },
        {
          "name": "Noam"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Abel"
    },
    {
      "name": "Awan",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enoch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Azura"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(flatten2(data));

function flatten2(obj) {
  let id = 0;
  return _flatten2(obj);

  function _flatten2(obj, ar = [], parentID = -1) {
    let node = {};
      node.id = id++;
      node.name = obj.name;
      if (parentID !== -1) { node.parent = parentID;}
      if (obj.size) { node.size = obj.size;}
      ar.push(node);

      if (obj.children) {
        for (let child of obj.children) {
          _flatten2(child, ar, node.id);
        }
      }
    return ar;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to transform the data without having to load the D3 script?

Comment: I just added a function based on plain javascript